# What should the SQL keyword "ISABOUT" [deprecated?] be replaced with?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deprecated, full-text-search, isabout

In MS SQL Full-text search, I'm using ISABOUT in my queries.

For example, this should return the top 10 `ProductIDs` (PK) with a `RANK` Field in the `ProductDetails` Table

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE( ProductDetails, *, ISABOUT("Nikon" WEIGHT (1.0), "Cameras" Weight(0.9)), 10 )
```

However, according to the [SQL Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms560697.aspx) `ISABOUT` is  deprecated.

So, I have two questions:

1. What is `ISABOUT` being replaced with?
2. DO I even NEED any extra `SQL Command` there? ( IOW, would just putting the search phrase 'Nikon Cameras' be better? )

What I was originally trying to accomplish here was to weight the first word the highest, then the second word lower, and keep descending to 0.5 where I would just rank the remaining words at 0.5.

My logic ( and perhaps it's flawed ) was that people's most relevant search words usually happen near the beginning of a phrase ( in English ).

- Am I going about this the wrong way?
- Is there a better way?
- Am I asking too many questions? (^_^)

Thanks all for your time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your link above refers to Enterprise Search, but for SQL Server full-text search, ISABOUT is still supported as part of the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) predicate and [CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) function.

This question was also covered in [a post to the MSDN SQL Server Search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/db06af32-ecda-4d33-bc65-5afb9bc2c0d7) forum.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting. I'm still a little fuzzy on what ISABOUT does.

Answer (score 2):

`ISABOUT` adds custom weights to your words which help in ranking the documents returned. For `CONTAINS()`, it does not do any ranking, this form has no influence.